# Can I sculpt a group of OBJs

Tags: objects, export, import, sculpting, groups

I have a group of OBJs (imported with vert order and poly groups intact),  specifically two upper arms and I want to sculpt one and have it mirrored on the other, but I do not want to combine them into a single OBJ, because I need to  export them separately, with their original vert order poly groups still intact.

I have them grouped, but when I go to sculpt mode I only have one OBJ selected,  and I can't seem to sculpt anything.

I'm probably missing something real obvious, or maybe trying to accomplish  something undo-able.

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: You can only edit one object at the time (grouping does not make them one object, they are still separate). In the outliner expand the group and select the object you need to edit, then press tab to enter edit mode.

Comment: I'm looking to sculpt not edit,  but I assume the same applies. If I combine both  objects into  a single object and then sculpt them  as such,  will it keep  the vert order and poly groups intact(with  the same internal names),  so  that  I can save the file,  delete all the points on one side,  export,  reload the file,  and repeat the process for the other side?

I need to  have a mirrored sculpt with  all internal  names remaining the same,  and still  be able to  export as separate OBJs.

Answer (score 0):

Okay  a little trial and error,  and I've figured this out.  I need to export both  objects together from  the original program(not Blender),  keep  the vert order,  and poly groups intact. Import into  Blender, still keeping everything intact.

Go  ahead and sculpt it as I normally would.  Save the file, and delete one half of the object,  and then export that(also  keeping vert  group order,  and poly groups).  Do  NOT save.  Close the file, open it back up  and delete the other side and export.  I now have the original two models,  right and left,  with  all internal  names intact.

Comment: And where and when do you do the mirroring of your arm?